# Indexing in dplyr using row indexes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and for some of the columns (the names of which I gathered in the vector named Variables) included in that df, I want to compute the ratio of the variables value for an observation, divided by the first observation of that observation's group, which is not zero.

How do I do that? I've tried the following:

```
if (Condition==1){
  for(i in 1:length(Variables)){
    colNum <- which(colnames(df)== Variables[i])
    df <- df %>% 
      group_by(Id) %>% 
      mutate(Column = .[[colNum]]/first(.[.[[colNum]]!=0, colNum][[1]]))
  }
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column `Column` must be length 6 (the group size) or one, not 246
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use `mutate_at` i.e. `%>% mutate_at(colNum, funs(Column = ./first(.[.!=0]))`. As a reproducible example `mtcars %>% mutate_at(8, funs(Column = ./first(.[. != 0])))  %>% head`

Comment: Still the same error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Column` must be length 8 (the group size) or one, not 0. I do not understand how it comes up with the group size of 8 (or 6 above). I have a dataset that contains 25 different groups...!

Comment: Are you getting error with the `mtcars` example as well? Please do a `print(colNum)` after line 3.  I am guessing that there some columns that are not in the 'df'

Comment: No. Something must be wrong with my data. I don't know what though. It's not grouped by any other column and all the data is numeric with no NAs or anything.

Comment: as there is no reproducible example, I would suggest to check by `print(colNum)` after line 3